# What were the most sold books in Esperanto in 2015?

Tags: culture, books

I remember seeing some statistics in a magazine of UEA. Does someone have some data in a freely and easily consultable format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the bestseller list from the magazine *Esperanto* (March 2016):

[image: Bona vendojaro: denove super 100 000 eŭroj]